# java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm

Tags: scala, playframework, migration, playframework-2.2

I tried to migrate play framework from 2.1.4 to 2.2.6, I changed plugins.sbt and build.properties as per the migration document.

### plugins.sbt

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")

### build.properties

sbt.version=0.13.0

### build.scala

```
  import sbt._
  import Keys._
  import play.Project._

  object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
   val appName = "Test-App"
   val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

   val appDependencies: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = Seq(
      javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean,
      "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4",    
      "com.wordnik" % "swagger-play2_2.10" % "1.3.6"
   )

   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion,                
              appDependencies).settings(
          ebeanEnabled := true,
          sources in doc in Compile := List()
      )

    }
```

I got the following exception while compiling,

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/home/Test-App/}Test-App:
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.10, _2.10.0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:47)
at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:30)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$61.apply(Defaults.scala:1027)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$61.apply(Defaults.scala:1027)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found some solutions, like removing scala-stm with exclude

```
"dependencyGroupId" %% "dependencyArtifactId" % "dependencyVersion" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")
```

I tried like this, 
    "org.scala-stm" % "scala-stm_2.10" % "2.2.6" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")

But I got the dependency unresolved exception,

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/Test-App}Test-App...
[info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;2.2.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;2.2.6
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /opt/play/repository/local/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10/2.2.6  
       /ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/home/Test-App/.m2/repository/org/scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10
     /2.2.6/scala-stm_2.10-2.2.6.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10/2.2.6 
     /scala-stm_2.10-2.2.6.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-stm/scala- 
   stm_2.10/2.2.6/scala-stm_2.10-2.2.6.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;2.2.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-stm#scala-   
  stm_2.10;2.2.6: not found
  at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
```

Here I dont know what is dependencyGroupId, dependencyArtifactId for org.scala-stm? Kindly help me to resolve this..

Comment: Do you have a `build.sbt` as well in root as well?

Comment: No. I dont have build.sbt. I have only build.scala, because migrate from 2.1.4 to 2.2.6.

Comment: The problem is that scala-stm_2.10/2.2.6 [does not exist](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cscala-stm). Try adding this to your appDependencies list: `"org.scala-stm" % "scala-stm_2.10" % "0.7"`

Comment: you could try a more mature sbt version like 0.13.5

Comment: Thanks Nio and Schleichardt. I figure out this issue occurs because of swagger playframework dependency "com.wordnik" % "swagger-play2_2.10" % "1.2.5".  I change swagger version that suits for play 2.2.6. Now it works fine.